# Lua allocator: what is type "something else"?

Tags: lua

Quoting the lua 5.4 documentation:

> When ptr is NULL, osize encodes the kind of object that Lua is allocating. osize is any of LUA_TSTRING, LUA_TTABLE, LUA_TFUNCTION, LUA_TUSERDATA, or LUA_TTHREAD when (and only when) Lua is creating a new object of that type. When osize is some other value, Lua is allocating memory for **something else**.

What exactly is something else and do I have any chance to get any insight into it?

Background:
I have an embedded lua project and thought it would be interesting to see what lua actually allocates and where most of the memory goes to. So I logged the types and created a cake diagram. Sadly, the percentage of "something else" is always over 70%. I dont even see the point of knowing whats allocated if there is such a high percentage of random lua temporary data or internal structures. I thought I could get some insight of how much memory is used for example for modules.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the code that reproduces this, or at least a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we know where to start looking.

Comment: Well it is hard to give a minimal example here. Not even sure for what. For the logging process? For the script? My current script just runs embedded and it contains about 10 files. But judging from your answer: Having so much memory as „something else“ does not seem to be normal? I was aimimg for an answer as general as possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this in the Lua mailing list. Thanks.